# How to find a string which doesnot contain a specific using regular expression in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a long string.

```
Example
This is a dog.
This is a cat.
A cat and a cat is a pet animal.
A tiger is a wild animal.
```

Now I want the string which does not contain 'cat' but contain a animal.
How can I do this using regex.
I know that I have to use(?!) but how that i dont know.
So the output would be

```
A tiger is a wild animal.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*\bThis\b).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/16

For you edited question use

```
^(?=.*\banimal\b)(?!.*\bcat\b).*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/18

Comment: @user3138879 You can drop the lookahead and use `^(?!.*\bcat\b).*\banimal\b.*$` (this processes faster)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a negative look-behind:

```
var s1 = "This is a dog.\nThis is a cat.\nA cat and a cat is a pet animal.\nA tiger is a wild animal.";
 var rx = new Regex(@"^.*(?<!\bcat\b.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
 var c = rx.Matches(s1).Cast<Match>().Select(d => d.Value.Trim()).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]